# VMPlayer - How can I create a "custom" Virtual Machine? (Need to set virtual harddrive from SCSI to IDE)

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine

I want to Create a New Virtual Machine from a Custom configuration from the Wizard. But the 'Custom' option has been removed and I can only create a new vm from a preexisting configuration (Windows XP/7/NT, Linux, Solaris, etc...).

I need to set the hard drive from SCSI to IDE, any idea how I can accomplish?

http://www.seopher.com/articles/configuring_vmware_for_ide_rather_than_scsi_good_for_installing_linux_
^^^explains how to create a 'custom' vm config in an older version of vmplayer.

[image: http://www.seopher.com/images/vmware/2.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to get the Custom option back but have you tried using the Pre-existing configuration that best matches the distro you want to install?

The reason the IDE virtual drive is sometimes recommended is that some Linux installers don't automatically load the driver module needed for the SCSI virtual device.  If you run the installer and it finds the drive, then you are good to go.

On the other hand, if you are really using VMWare Player and not VMWare Server/Workstation/ESX then maybe you are just trying to run an already installed VM?  In that case, you should need to worry about SCSI vs IDE.

Comment: @stu: Thanks for the advice, but I'm trying to install OSX 10.4.8 using an excellent guide at http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Vmware_how_to. Unfortunately I need to use a Windows NT config with an IDE virtual hd. I'm able to get to the partition part of the setup, but the installer can't find the suci hd :(.

Comment: eww, installing OSX in VMware? I wouldn't bother...it's horribly slow, since there is no graphics acceleration